# request csv format data from url using python

Tags: python

i wana simply send a request to the following url and recive data in csv format and save on the following location,but doest not work!any help will be appreciated

```
from urllib import  request

my_url='http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=CSV&a=07&b=9&  c=1996&d=05&e=26&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv'

def rciveURL(getURL):
response=request.urlopen(getURL)
csv=response.read()
csv_str=str(csv)
mydstination=r'mori.csv'
fx=open(mydstination,"w")
for line in csv_str:
  fx.write(line+"\n")
  fx.closed()

  rciveURL(my_url)
```

Comment: Indentation level at function rciveURL() seems wrong. Is it just a typo?

Comment: As noted, your code isn't formatted properly.  Also, requests is a third party replacement for the standard urllib.  So pick which one you want.  Requests is easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to receive a file from `url` and save a file at `save_dest` is:

```
import urllib
file = urllib.URLopener()
file.retrieve(url, save_dest)
```